# Cannot set a file association to a program that I manually moved to Program Files

Tags: windows-7, file-association

I downloaded Notepad2 and placed it in

> `C:\Program Files\Notepad2`

I wanted to associate all `.txt` files to Notepad2. I did an Open With and Choose Default Program. I browsed to and selected Notepad2 and clicked OK. But, the application didn't show up as an option in the Open with dialog box.

I moved the Notepad2 directory to `Program Files (x86)` and tried again, same problem.

Comment: Not an actual answer but Notepad++ could do the job and has a menu just for this (Settings > Preferences > File > Association).

Comment: I'm having this problem with any application that doesn't have an installer. That I put in Program Files manually (for example, Reflector for opening .dll files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the application in a folder under my user account and the association dialog works correctly. For example

> `C:\Users\anthony\Downloads\Notepad2`

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating a persistent context entry in windows right-click menu:

1. first of all backup you registry --> http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Back-up-the-registry
2. in registry editor go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell`
3. right click on 'shell' container and crate a new key called (i.e.) "Open with Notepad2" w/o quotes
4. now right click on the newly crated key and crate a new key called Command (it will be nested in "Open with Notepad2"
5. select the key 'command' and in the right pane double click on the 'Default' value and enter:

   fullpath_of_notepad2.exe %1

NOTE: use the real full path of notepad2 in place of "fullpath_of_notepad2.exe" and remember that if you move the executable the context menu will stop working.

I have tried this with some apps w/o install (i.e portable apps).

As an alternative (I did not tried it but is freeware) you can try [Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/) which have a more friendly and complete functionality for managing file associations.

Comment: +1 for Default Programs Editor, it is an excellent program :)

Answer (score 0):

## Notepad2 Installer!

*For this specific case only*

Flo has released an [installer](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) that *replaces* the default Notepad with Notepad2.